# Complexheatmap zoom annotation : Cluster wise boxplot

Tags: r, heatmap

I want show cluster wise boxplot distribution from complexheatmap. I was able to do row-wise distribution but how do I implement the cluster-wise distribution attached as example.

In the dummy example it creates a subgroup which it shows in the distribution. Similar manner I have already in my datafile made cluster which is represented in the first column.

How do I implement this in my dataframe using this [example](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap/reference/anno_zoom.html#see-also) code

I'm not sure how do I make subgroup in case of my dataframe.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

This is the output i would like to see:
[image: out put i want to see]

This is the output I have:

[image: output I have]

The dataset is this one: [small_data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OnMBqpF9O692KaQwUs6Cu9fpwtPA69PP/view?usp=sharing)

And my code:

```
df <- read.csv("small_data.txt",header = TRUE)
heat <- t(scale(t(df[,3:ncol(df)])))
myBreaks <- seq(-1.5, 1.5, length.out=100)
hmap <- Heatmap(heat)
hmap
```

How do i implement the cluster specific distribution ? as it is shown in the first pic. The second figure is what I'm getting now

Comment: Hi PesKchan, I think you will be much more likely to receive an answer if you substantially simplify your question with only the *absolute minimum* amount of code necessary to show the issue.

Comment: okay i would like implement this code https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap/reference/anno_zoom.html#see-also